# How to print in multiple columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code:

```
for i in range(2, 13):
  print(i, "Multiplication table")
  for j in range(1, 13):
    print(i, "x", j, " = ", i * j)
  print()
```

How can I print the output in columns?

Comment: There's an existing question, [Printing Lists as Tabular Data](/q/9535954/4518341). Is that what you're asking? Do the answers answer your question? For tips, see [ask]. You can [edit] your post to add details if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key is to use lists.

```
multiplications = []

for i in range(2, 13):
    multiplications.append([f"multiplication table of {i}" if j == 0 else j*i for j in range(0, 13)])

for table in multiplications:
    print(table)
```